# I have an EditText field which I want saved for when the app is opened again

Tags: android, android-edittext, save, restore

I have an EditText field called ed. It will store some text that the user will need when the app is started again. I will need to save the text so that when the app is opened again it is back in the EditText field. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharedPreference is a way to go.

**The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).**

Here is the example to implement SharedPreferences.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

or

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html

or

One more basic thing you can look up is the example implementation given in the APIDemos of android. APIDemos sample application has all basic examples one need to know.

Comment: Thank you. Love that blog too, but never seen this entry.

Comment: Hi Tim, you might want to mark the answer right. if you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way would be to store it as key-value in prefs (putString/getString):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: How would such a thing be implemented?